# Navigation links not binding into "More" option in Priority Menu responsive width in header while using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

While using JS the menu items are not bind into "More" when there is no responsive width in header and JQuery code is working fine but JS code not working. Please give me the solution.

JQuery Code working fine. here is the JQuery code. Need solution in JS.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    function calcWidth() {
    var navwidth = 0;
    var morewidth = $('#SB-smartMenuList .SB-moreHeaderPages').outerWidth(true);
    $('#SB-smartMenuList > li:not(.SB-moreHeaderPages)').each(function() {
        navwidth += $(this).outerWidth( true );
    });
    
    var availablespace = $('.SB-smartMenu').width() - morewidth;
  
    if (navwidth > availablespace) {
        var lastItem = $('#SB-smartMenuList > li:not(.SB-moreHeaderPages)').last();
        lastItem.attr('data-width', lastItem.outerWidth(true));
        lastItem.prependTo($('#SB-smartMenuList .SB-moreHeaderPages ul'));
        calcWidth();
    } else {
        
    var firstMoreElement = $('#SB-smartMenuList li.SB-moreHeaderPages li').first();
    if (navwidth + firstMoreElement.data('width') < availablespace) {
        firstMoreElement.insertBefore($('#SB-smartMenuList .SB-moreHeaderPages'));
    }
}
if ($('.SB-moreHeaderPages li').length > 0) {
    $('.SB-moreHeaderPages').css('display','block');
    } else {
        $('.SB-moreHeaderPages').css('display','none');
    }
}
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
    calcWidth();
});
$(".SB-dropdownMore").hide();
$('.SB-moreHeaderPages').hover(function(){
    $('.SB-dropdownMore').show();
    }, function(){
    $('.SB-dropdownMore').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you have a problem with your attempt to rewrite this to plain JavaScript - then provide a proper [mre] of what you tried.